# GoLand fails to update Go Modules. Go list -m -json all (pkgserver.com) fails

Tags: go, goland

I am getting an error whereby any imports defined in the Go.Mod file are not being resolved. An error message stating "go list -m json all (pkgserver.com) Failed to Run" is displayed. This includes imports from our own server, and github.

In the 'Run' tab I am getting a list of statements stating to check access rights and connection failures for pkgserver.com, (exit status 128, Operation Timed Out, Could Not Read from Remote Repository) but imports from public repos on github are also not being recognised by GoLand in code.

I checked and confirmed that the Global 'GOPATH' includes the default go folder, project root folder and disabled 'Index entire GOPATH'. Also checked that Go modules integration is enabled...

Can you help please? As I am not sure what to do, I am new to Golang.

Comment: What is the go version you've defined in go.mod file and what is the version you're running it?

Comment: An example of `go.mod` file would be helpful.